# SoapUI doesn't send client certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, soapui

Using SoapUI 5.2.1 with the SSL client cert configured...

A python request to the endpoint like so

```
import requests

HOST = 'https://HOST'
CERT_FILE = 'CERT.crt'
KEY_FILE = 'KEY.key'

ping_response = requests.get(HOST, cert=(CERT_FILE, KEY_FILE))
print(ping_response)
```

works fine, but when I turned the cert/key into a PFX or a java keystore and load it into SoapUI like so

http://geekswithblogs.net/gvdmaaden/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-configure-soapui-with-client-certificate-authentication.aspx

I run a request and get a 400 Bad Request response with a body of "No required SSL certificate was sent"

It seems that the client cert is not being sent. Is there another step to configuring SoapUI for client auth? Do I need to specifically link it to the project or request somewhere?